# How to indent xml literals in emacs scala-mode

Tags: xml, scala, emacs

When using scala-mode in emacs, xml is not formatted very will (all of the tags are indented at the same level). This is terribly annoying. Is there any way to indent the xml in a hierarchial manner, either with scala-mode directly or with mmm-mode. I have tried to write a class with mmm-add-classes, but couldn't get it to work.

Here is what I tried

```
(mmm-add-classes
  '((scala-xml
     :submode nxml-mode
     :face mmm-declaration-submode-face
     :front "<([\w:]+)\s?.*>"
     :back "</~1>"
     :save-matches 1)))
```